# Find string matches count in list using Python

Tags: python, list, search, python-3.x

I read a text file for some analysis, each word is appended to a list and given an id

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
with fi as myfile:
  for line in myfile:
    for item in line.split(' '):
      db[0].append(id_+1)
      db[2].append(item)
      ...more stuff
```

Then I search for each word through the list to find its matches, and store the count as **sim1**. If a match is found, I test if the next word matches the consecutive one as well, and store its count as **sim2**. Similarly for **sim3**. My code looks like:

```
for i in range(id_-3):
  sim1=0
  sim2=0
  sim3=0
  for j in range(id_-3):
    if i==j:  continue;
    if db[2][i] == db[2][j]:
      sim1 += 1
      if db[2][i+1] == db[2][j+1]:
        sim2 += 1
        if db[2][i+2] == db[2][j+2]:
          sim3 += 1
  db[3].append(sim1)
  db[4].append(sim2)
  db[5].append(sim3)
```

This works, but it's too slow!
I believe python provides faster search methods, but I'm still a Py newbie!

Comment: example input/output?

Comment: Looks like you could benefit from changing how you store the data. For example, turn it into a mapping (dictionary) of words to a list of indices. Then you can check those lists for consecutive values. No searching at all. In other words; you're not looking for faster Python, you're looking for a better algorithm.

Comment: Just use a dictionary! It will make your life a lot easier and requiring less code and will most likely speed it up

Comment: I read http://docs.python.org/3.1/tutorial/datastructures.html it says dictionaries are unordered key-value pairs. How can I count words matching: db[2][i+1] == db[2][j+1] for example. I'm still learning python, I really appreciate elaborating a working example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The slowness in your algorithm mainly comes from the fact that you have an inner loop which iterates len(db[2]) times contained within an outer loop which also iterates len(db[2]) times.  This means the inner code is executing len(db[2])^2 times.  If your file is large and you are parsing 5000 words, for example, then the code runs 5000^2 = 25,000,000 times!

So, the angle of attack to solve the problem is to find a way to eliminate or significantly reduce the cost of that inner loop. Below is an example solution which only needs to iterate through len(db[2]) one time, and then does a second separate loop which iterates through a much smaller set of items. There are a few inner loops within the second iteration, but they run an even smaller number of times and have almost inconsequential cost.

I timed your algorithm and my algorithm using a text file which weighed in at about 48kb.  Your algorithm averaged about 14 seconds on my computer and my algorithm averaged 0.6 seconds. So, by taking away that inner loop, the algorithm is now over 23 times faster. I also made some other minor optimizations, such as changing the comparison to be between numbers rather than text, and creating the storage arrays at full size from the start in order to avoid using append(). Append() causes the interpreter to dynamically increase the array's size as needed, which is slower.

```
from collections import defaultdict

# Create zero-filled sim1, sim2, sim3 arrays to avoid append() overhead
len_ = len(db[2]) - 2
for _ in range(3):
    db.append([0] * len_)

# Create dictionary, containing d['word'] = [count, [indexes]]
# Do just one full iteration, and make good use of it by calculating
# sim1 (as 'count') and storing an array of number indexes for each word,
# allowing for a very efficient loop coming up...
d = defaultdict(lambda: [0, []])
for index, word in enumerate(db[2]):
    if index < len_:
        # Accumulate sim1
        d[word][0] += 1 
    # Store all db[2] indexes where this word exists
    d[word][1].append(index) 

# Now loop only through words which occur more than once (smaller loop)
for word, (count, indexes) in d.iteritems():
    if count > 1:
        # Place the sim1 values into the db[3] array
        for i in indexes:
            if i < len_:
                db[3][i] = count - 1
                # Look for sim2 matches by using index numbers
                next_word = db[2][i+1]
                for next_word_index in d[next_word][1]:
                    if next_word_index - 1 != i and next_word_index - 1 in indexes:
                        # Accumulate sim2 value in db[4]
                        db[4][i] += 1
                        # Look for sim3 matches
                        third_word = db[2][i+2]
                        if third_word == db[2][next_word_index + 1]:
                            # Accumulate sim3 value in db[5]
                            db[5][i] += 1
```

Answer (score -2):

Yep, you're performaing a string compare. That's really slow.
What you want is to compile your string as a regular pattern. :)

Have a look onto the libary *re* from python.
[Python: re](http://docs.python.org/3.2/library/re.html)

Comment: -1: a string compare is not "really slow" - it'll be faster than using an re for a simple compare... `re` is not a useful suggestion in this case

Comment: Really? I have done a search with compiled regexes on a file which contains 3M entrys in a better amount of time then using string compares.

Comment: What was the pattern you were using ?

Comment: Don't got the files atm... But all of them where non simple regexes for matching special product names.